# Difference in the agg() function after a groupByKey() on a Dataset between Spark 2.3 and Spark 2.4

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I noticed a difference between the output of the `agg()` `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset` function when it's called after a `groupByKey`.

Let’s consider the following dataset `df` :

```
+----+---------+-----+
|name|  id     |score|
+----+---------+-----+
| aaa|      100|   12|
| aaa|      200|   29|
| bbb|      200|   53|
| bbb|      300|   42|
+----+---------+-----+
```

If we run the following code in the two environments (Spark v2.3.0 and Spark v2.4.8):

```
df.groupByKey(_.id).agg(collect_list($"name").as[Array[Option[String]]])
```

We will get two different schemas as an output:

**Spark 2.3.0** : `[key: struct<value: int>, collect_list(name): array<string>]`

**Spark 2.4.8** : `[value: int, collect_list(name): array<string>]`

So if we want to access the value column which is the `groupByKey` key, we will proceed differently depending on which Spark version we’re using:

**Spark 2.3.0** : `df.groupByKey(_.id).agg(collect_list($"name").as[Array[Option[String]]]).select($"key.value")`

**Spark 2.4.8** : `df.groupByKey(_.id).agg(collect_list($"name").as[Array[Option[String]]]).select($"value")`

The `groupByKey` function gives the same result in the two environments

I couldn't find a mention of this change in the documentation. Does someone have an explanation for this breaking change?

Comment: Second bullet point here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#datasetdataframe-apis might have something to do with it.

Comment: @mazaneicha I don't think so , because as I mentioned the groupByKey output didn't change between these two versions , the problem is more in the agg() function. and the doc bullet point you're mentioning is more related to the move from Spark 2.4 to Spark 3.0 which is not my case